# System is running in low graphics coupled with BSOD (Dual Boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ati, graphics

I had a nicely working dual boot until I shut down my laptop yesterday. Today, when I booted it up, I got this error on my Ubuntu:

[image]

I tried changing my display manager to **gdm**. It got worse, I couldn't even access my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

I went on to my Windows. Booted normally, fired up chrome, tried to open up stackoverflow. Everything froze and I was greeted by a BSOD. It said **BAD_POOL_HEADER**.

I restarted my windows again. it worked perfectly for 5 min and there it was again. I never had a BSOD before in my life.

Here are some more details about my system:

- I have a dual boot installation of Win 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04
- I never had a BSOD before
- I had installed my graphics driver (On Ubuntu) a month ago, and updated the system a few days ago. Basically nothing happened yesterday that'd cause my system to misbehave
- I thought this might be a hardware issues, but *Dell Diagnostics* ran all the tests perfectly.
- My laptop had heated up yesterday.

Can it be a hardware issue? If not, what can the possible fix be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like it is indeed a hardware issue, as you both mentioned heating up and also the fact that both systems started misbehaving again yesterday.

What were you doing exactly when it heated up? (physical conditions, like where the laptop was whenever that happened)

Comment: My laptop ran a Django server for a couple of hours. And yeah, it *does* seem to be a hardware issue. I reinstalled Linux, and I got an error, `Ring test failed; hardware acceleration disabled` on my boot screen.

Comment: Um, OK, so that Linux could still have software rendering? I haven't seen any that could do that :-?? Or you get no graphics at all? [curious]

Comment: problem fixed. Hardware issue it was. Check out the comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since both OSes had issues, it is not a software issue.

Diagnostics cannot check all the possible functions of the hardware. 
You may be lucky, perhaps it's simply a temperature issue and it's freezing on overheating.

What kinds of temperatures are you seeing on CPU and GPU? Does your bios have a system event log? Does it show any failure warnings?

If you have a Dell laptop, you may be able to get the thermal system mananger screen as follows  (do it after pausing grub during boot) :

Fn + 1 5 3 2 4 - An indicator LED starts flashing.

Fn + R - Shows you the thermal management screen, with options to set the throttling and fan speed

Comment: Turns out, it was indeed a hardware issue. Thanks to awesome service by Dell, I got my motherboard replaced. Apparently my GPU had malfunctioned due to overheating.